# Pandas data frame select all rows less than a column content float values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below.I need to select all rows from the data frame where column values are less than or equal to 0.3768. But I am getting an error.

Below is my dataframe.

[image]

I need to select all rows where column value is less than or equal to 0.3768.

Below is my code

```
for column in df_thd_funct_mode1_T:
 
new_df = df_thd_funct_mode1_T.loc[(np.isclose(df_thd_funct_mode1_T[column] <= .3768))]
```

I am getting an error as shown below.

**TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'**

May I know how to solve this issue

I run the script provided by Christian.But I am getting values greater than .3768 in my new data frame.

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate, what exactly you are trying to achieve here? Because your iterating over the columns looks very suspicious. By always assigning it to new_df you will only get the result of the last column nevertheless, or did you omit some code that would come afterwards?
Here you generally have two possible problems: There is one column, that is actually a string, so that will not at all work. Or the float value is just stored as a string. then `df_thd_funct_model1_T[column].astype(float)` could work.

Comment: Ok thank you. I am new to this. I am basically a circuit designer. I need to select all rows where column values are less than 0.3768

Comment: But if you say "column values", do you mean that in case there is any column with a value less than 0.3768 or one specific one? For the first case I added an answer. For the other you maybe would have to specify, which column you mean.

Comment: I need to select all rows whose value is based on first column named index.I need all rows where the value of column name  index is 0.3768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this here:

`new_df = df_thd_funct_mode1_T[df_thd_funct_mode1_T.apply(lambda row: all(float(column) <= .3768 for column in row), axis=1)]`

Here you do not need the loop any more that you had in your example.

I basically go through the dataframe there and for each row I check, whether `all` values are less than .3768.

If you want to filter such, that you accept the row as soon as there is any value less than .3768 in that row, you have to replace `all` with `any`.

This of course will only work under the condition, that all columns only contain floats. If not, then you will run into an Error, trying to cast that into a float.

Comment: I updated the question, if you don't mind could you please check the same.

Comment: @Hari ah, maybe I understood the question wrong. You want all values to be less than .3768? Then you will have to change the `any` by `all`. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: Yes 'all' is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check multiple columns you have to add to condition every column check. Every condition should be like:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] <= 0.3768 ]
```

Check these examples it should be helpful to your question: https://www.statology.org/pandas-select-rows-based-on-column-values/